# How to locate app crash logs in iPhone & iPad?

Tags: ios, iphone, crash-reports

If any iOS app crashes some crash logs are generated on behalf of that app.
How to find the location of such crash logs. Please help.

I want crash logs inside the iPhone/iPad, not really using XCode to see the crash logs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think he/she asked about crash logs inside the iPhone/iPad, not really using XCode to see the crash logs.

To check the crash logs inside iPhone/iPad, you have to go to

**Settings -> General -> About -> Diagnostics & Usage -> Diagnostic & Usage Data**

You will see the crash log with the Title **APPName_Date....**

Attached the screen shot of one of the crash logs below:-

[image]

Answer (score 48):

you can find crash report on iPad/iphone below location for iOS:

IOS7 & Below = **Settings --> General --> About --> Diagnostics & Usage --> Diagnotstic & Usage Data**

IOS8 & IOS9 = **Settings --> Privacy --> Diagnostics & Usage --> Diagnotstic & Usage Data**

IOS10 & Above = **Settings --> Privacy --> Analytics --> Analytics Data**

Comment: And where are they in iOS 14?

Answer (score 6):

https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT202100

**IOS 7 & Below** = Settings --> General --> About --> Diagnostics & Usage --> Diagnotstic & Usage Data

**IOS 8 & Above** = Settings --> Privacy --> Diagnostics & Usage --> Diagnotstic & Usage Data

**IOS 10.2** = Settings --> Privacy -->Analytics --> Diagnotstic & Usage Data

**IOS 10.3.2 and Above** = Settings --> Privacy --> Analytics --> Analytics Data

[image]

Comment: And where are they in iOS 14?

Answer (score 0):

From [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1747/_index.html):

Even though you won't be able to run the app in Xcode's debugger, Xcode can still give you all the information you need to debug the problem.

1) Plug in the device and open Xcode

2) Open the Organizer window and select the Devices tab

3) Under the DEVICES section in the left column, expand the listing for the device

4) Select Device Logs to see crash logs or select Console to see Console output

OR
[image]

Comment: Or alternatively you can download and install iPhone Configuration Utility software and check your crash logs after connecting your device.

Comment: For XCode 7 it's the menu Window -> Devices and no longer found under Organizer.