# iOS : Extensions crash not being reported

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios-extensions

I have a network extension and it is crashing after some usage.I think its a memory issue.Is there any tool that can report extension crashes as well?

I want to be sure about the reason of crash.

PS: Extension is running in 'release' mode.

I have tried Window->Devices->View Device Logs. **No Crash there**

Tried Window->Organizer->Crashes **No Crash there**

Crashlytics and Instabug are not reporting it too.

Tried in Xcode 10 but no joy in its Device logs too.

Comment: check here https://stackoverflow.com/a/43730440/6898523

Comment: They are not reporting many crashes too.